# Reading Binary PLists in Ruby on Rails Natively / on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, info.plist

I need to pull some data from an app's Info.plist (the bundle version number), which is a binary XML done by apple. The PList gem only does writing, and Plist4r needs the command line plutil (near as I can tell), which I don't have access to on Heroku.

So, anyone have a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and decided to use this gem: https://github.com/ckruse/CFPropertyList

Comment: CFPropertyList gem showing error at require statement. Can you please help me over it.